# how just get url with html type with jsoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I want to only download sites with content type "text/html" and do not download pdf/mp4/rar... files

for now my code is this:

```
 Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(linkInfo.getLink()).followRedirects(false).validateTLSCertificates(false).userAgent(USER_AGENT);

 Document htmlDocument = connection.get();

 if (!connection.response().contentType().contains("text/html")) {

     return;
 }
```

Isn't there any thing like:

```
Jsoup.connect(linkInfo.getLink()).contentTypeOnly("text/html");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you need a way to know if a file is HTML before actually downloading it, then you can use a HEAD request. This will request just the headers, so you can check if it is `text/html` before actually downloading the file. The method you were using does not really work because you are downloading the file and parsing it as HTML *before* checking, which will throw an exception on non-HTML files.

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(linkInfo.getLink())
    .method(Connection.Method.HEAD)
    .validateTLSCertificates(false)
    .followRedirects(false)
    .userAgent(USER_AGENT);

Connection.Response head = connection.execute();
if (!head.contentType().contains("text/html")) return;

Document html = Jsoup.connect(head.url())
    .validateTLSCertificates(false)
    .followRedirects(false)
    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
    .get();
```

Comment: for some sebsite it throw 404 error when using method(Connection.Method.HEAD) although the url is valid with no 404 error